Getting cors error when trying to code subscription purchase through stripe and firebase
When I run my function to make a stripe purchase the browser throws this error:

Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-smallgistics-cd63d.cloudfunctions.net/createStripeSubscription' from origin 'https://smallgistics.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Any ideas?
Server-side code:
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors');
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_51NdbMmEls8dLhARfYdtPdL3o7oSszlYaZJE7GMYhvPtpjgGXjGYXLPlEwhD5n4sXZFR0NtaAar1qQQzG6PKEnI9M000ccfgqwX');

var serviceAccount = require('./smallgistics-cd63d-firebase-adminsdk-dev8o-b099ac3121.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://smallgistics-cd63d.firebaseio.com'
});

exports.createStripeSubscription = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const corsHandler = cors({origin: true});
  corsHandler(request, response, async () => {
    const userId = request.body.userId; // The ID of the user in your Firebase auth
    const productId = 'prod_Pw1OIYAqg3JuG8'; // The ID of the product in Stripe

    try {
      // Retrieve the Stripe customer ID from Firestore
      const doc = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId).get();
      const customer = doc.data().stripeCustomerId;

      // Create the subscription
      const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
        customer: customer,
        items: [{ product: productId }],
      });

      response.send({ subscriptionId: subscription.id });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      response.status(500).send(error);
    }
  });
});

Client-side code:
  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyBmLNOykJH7eAaSxQZsD5P7IlQhUQtBm5k",
      authDomain: "smallgistics-cd63d.firebaseapp.com",
      projectId: "smallgistics-cd63d",
      storageBucket: "smallgistics-cd63d.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "641898304430",
      appId: "1:641898304430:web:9a7aecf59ea12dc0822e3f",
      measurementId: "G-WR83XXQHC0"
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    window.onload = function() {
      // Set up an auth state changed listener
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          // User is signed in, set up the button click handler
          const subscribeButton = document.getElementById('subscribeButton');
          if (subscribeButton) {
            subscribeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
              // Determine the URL to use based on the environment
              const functionURL = location.hostname === 'localhost' || location.hostname === '127.0.0.1'
                ? 'http://127.0.0.1:5002/smallgistics-cd63d/us-central1/createStripeSubscription'
                : 'https://us-central1-smallgistics-cd63d.cloudfunctions.net/createStripeSubscription';

              // Call the Firebase function
              fetch(functionURL, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ userId: user.uid }),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
              })
              .then(response => response.json())
              .then(data => console.log(data))
              .catch(error => console.error(error));
            });
          } else {
            console.error('The element with ID subscribeButton does not exist.');
          }
        } else {
          // User is signed out
          console.log('No user is signed in.');
        }
      });
    };
  </script>  


Any ideas?
Made extensive changes to both client and server side code.  Use tutorials and Co-pilot in VS Code.  Nothing works

Firebase functions v2 has a simple config for enabling cors so you don't have to try to write any extra code for that. See the documentation.

Thank you, Doug.  i will look it over now
